# Regex star produces no match

Tags: regex, bash

If memory serves I used to be able to do this:

```
$ [[ abc123 =~ ([0-9]*) ]]
   
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

As you can see it's giving no output with the star `*` character. Now it only works if I use the plus `+` character.

```
$ [[ abc123 =~ ([0-9]+) ]]

$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
123
```

### Edit

See more strangeness. It will match the start of the string, but not the end of the string.

```
$ [[ 123abc =~ ([0-9]*) ]]

$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
123
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex returns the first match that it finds, that is position 0, before the "a", there it matches the empty string.

`*` as quantifier is difficult, because if that is the whole expression, it is able to match the empty string, and therefor it will match on each position where is no digit to match.

So in the string "abc123" it matches 4 times!

```
 a b c 123
^ ^ ^  ^..
```

the first 3 times it is happy to match the empty string and on the fourth position it matches the series of digits.